# Kill any service running at a specific port

Tags: process, kill, tcp

I am trying to write a script that kills service running at a specific port. This is my script:

```
a=$(ps ax | grep 4990 | grep java | awk '{print $1}')
kill -9 $a
```

It's a java program. This script works sometimes, but mysteriously fails most of the time.

Is there any other way to kill a service running on a port? My port is `4990`.

Comment: Your script would also kill Java processes running on other pets such as 14990.

Answer (score 58):

You can try `fuser`:

```
fuser -k 4990/tcp
```

Or using `lsof` to get the process id, then feed to `kill`:

```
kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:4990)
```

Comment: Should I have to replace tcp with java?

Comment: @Abhishekdotpy: No, use `tcp`.

Comment: Thank you for that `-t` flag, I have needed that for so long.

Comment: Could you give a hint on how to properly pass last line to ssh?

Comment: @VladimirProtsenko can you provide more context?

Comment: @cuonglm the question is how to kill a process on the remote machine that is running on specific port. naive ssh remote-ip-address "kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:4990)" is not working.

Comment: @VladimirProtsenko then you want to quote instead of double quote to prevent command substitution run.

Comment: @cuonglm thanks

Comment: fuser -k 4990/tcp helps me everytime.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to kill any service or process running on port number 8080 then first you need to find the 8080 port process identification number(PID) and then kill it. Run the following command to find 8080 port number PID:

```
sudo lsof -t -i:8080
```

Here,

- **sudo** - command to ask admin privilege(user id and password).
- **lsof** - list of files(Also used for to list related processes)
- **-t** - show only process ID
- **-i** - show only internet connections related process
- **:8080** - show only processes in this port number

So you can now easily kill your PID using following command:

```
sudo kill -9 <PID>
```

Here,

- kill - command to kill the process
- -9 - forcefully

You can use one command to to kill a process on a specific port using the following command:

```
sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:8000)
```

For more you can see the following link
[How to kill a process on a specific port on linux](https://mr-khan.gitlab.io/linux/2018/05/02/kill-specific-port-on-linux.html)

Comment: Using `kill -9` gives the target process no opportunity to tidy up. Consider using plain `kill`, at least initially.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  $port = $argv[1]; 
  if(!empty($port) && is_numeric($port) ){
  $pid = trim(shell_exec("lsof -t -i:".$port));
  if(!empty($pid)){
     shell_exec("sudo kill -9 ".$pid);
     echo "pid : ".$pid."  killed which is listened port : ".$port."\xA";
  }
  else{
     echo " [X] no such process found for pid : ".$port."\xA";
  }
  }
  else{ 
     echo " invalid pid \xA";
  }
?>
```

1. create a php file `kill.php`
2. run the php file with required port `$ php kill.php 8088`

Comment: Using `kill -9` gives the target process no opportunity to tidy up. Consider using plain `kill`, at least initially.

Comment: +1 for using PHP for this task.

Comment: @G-Man by mistake it added

Comment: @Bananguin to kill exact process id of the given port am using this when executing bunch process with jenkins

Comment: when running script files and its contain `lsof -t -i:port_id` command when build process the `port_id` or `process id` of `port_id` may be empty, that time we get some command error, to avoid that kind of error am used this. here i can kill exact process id of the given port