# How can I kill a process running on a specific IP and port?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, command-line, process, kill

I was wondering, is there any way to kill a process that is running on a specific IP **and** port on Ubuntu 14.04 on a local IP and port? Preferably, this would be in one command, but if not, a bash script would be perfectly fine as well.

Comment: by "running" do you mean "listening" or "connected to", and by IP do you mean local or remote, and by port, do you mean local or remote? What Operating System?

Comment: linking: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/140482/117549

Comment: I already know about fuser, and by running I mean listening to. It is Ubuntu 14.04, and IP and port are local.

Comment: please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/365697/edit) your question (and tags) to clarify

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are likely cleaner ways, but something along the lines of:

```
netstat -lnp | grep 'tcp .*127.0.0.1:9984' | sed -e 's/.*LISTEN *//' -e 's#/.*##' | xargs kill
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `ss` we can get details of process/connections which are listening on a specific IP and port, for src `127.0.0.1` and port `80`:

```
sudo ss -lp  '( dport = :80 )' src 127.0.0.1
```

then we can only get the `PID`'s using `grep` and kill them all using `xargs` and `kill`.

```
sudo ss -lp  '( dport = :80 )' src 127.0.0.1 | grep -Po "(?<=pid=).*(?=,)"\
| sort | uniq | xargs kill
```

You can also use `-a` switch instead of `-l` to get a list of all listening and non-listening sockets.

Answer (score 3):

`fuser` on Linux has an option which does exactly what you are looking to do.

For example, `fuser 80/tcp` will print the PID of the process bound on that port and `fuser -k 80/tcp` will kill that process.

Comment: Please provide the answer with explanation so that your answer stands alone.

Answer (score 1):

On linux, as **root**, you can use either

```
ss -ptan
```

or

```
netstat -ntulp
```

to get a list of all running processes that "listen"(in this case tcp, replace the "t" with "u" for udp).

So one liner, to kill process listening on port 80, would look something like that:

```
ss -tanp | grep 80 | head -1 | sed 's_.*pid=\(.*\),.*_\1_' | xargs kill
```

Comment: `grep 80` would match something like `172.217.22.280:45581`. I don't think that's intentional. You probably want to do a match like `ss -tanp | awk '$1=="LISTEN" && $4=="<IP>:<PORT>" { print $6 }'`

Comment: Yes it will... I need a better regex. Will update it.

Answer (score -1):

The only IP a process on the local machine can run on is `127.0.0.1`, `lo`, the loopback device, that's known as `localhost`. Ports there can be forwarded to a public IP address with network configurations.

I usually use `sudo lsof -i :<port>` to see what's causing an [EADDRINUSE](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) because it's quicker to type.

```
sudo lsof -i :443 | tail -1 | cut -f2 -d' ' | xargs kill
```

Will kill the process running on port 443, if your `lsof` gives output like:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
python3 32233  cat    4u  IPv4 24123106      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

From `lsof --help`:

```
-i i   select by IPv[46] address: [46][proto][@host|addr][:svc_list|port_list]
```

Comment: What's wrong with this answer? Explain your votes, *se vous plaît*